# How to save an website with SVG's as an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, webpage-screenshot

How do you save a webpage that contains a referenced CSS file and has multiple SVG images as an image or pdf? It doesn't look like html2canvas supports SVGs.

Comment: If we are talking about server-side JS, you could use something like nightmare or puppeteer.

Comment: Unfortunately this will be run client-side